How to check if the given input value is null or not in RoomDB-SQL?

I'm writing an SQL query that returns data based on several conditions. One of these conditions is related to the senders field. If the senders value, which is an input parameter from the user, is null, I want to skip this specific condition and continue with the rest. However, the condition should be applied if senders is not null and contains a value.

P.S.: I'm using Room and Kotlin.
TLDR:
if(senders.isEmpty()){
    skipToNextConditions()
}else{
    applyTheCondition()
}


This is how the current Query looks like:

@Query(
    "SELECT * FROM localMail " +
    "WHERE (CASE WHEN :senders IS NOT NULL THEN `from` IN (:senders) END)" +
    "AND (isStarred = :inStarred OR isInTrash = :inTrash OR isInInbox = :inInbox OR hasAttachments = :hasAttachments OR isArchived = :inArchive) " +
    "AND (TRIM(:query) <> '' AND TRIM(:query) IS NOT NULL) " +
    "AND (rawMail COLLATE NOCASE LIKE '%' || :query || '%' OR subject COLLATE NOCASE LIKE '%' || :query || '%' OR intro COLLATE NOCASE LIKE '%' || :query || '%')"
)
fun queryAllSessionMails(
    senders: List<From>?,
    query: String,
    hasAttachments: Boolean,
    inInbox: Boolean,
    inStarred: Boolean,
    inArchive: Boolean,
    inTrash: Boolean,
): Flow<List<LocalMail>>


This query throws a runtime error which says:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "IS": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM localMail WHERE  (CASE WHEN  IS NOT NULL THEN `from` IN () END) AND (isStarred=? OR isInTrash = ? OR isInInbox = ? OR hasAttachments = ? OR isArchived = ?) AND accountId = (SELECT accountId FROM localMailAccount WHERE isACurrentSession = 1 LIMIT 1) AND (TRIM(?) <> '' AND TRIM(?) IS NOT NULL)AND (rawMail COLLATE NOCASE LIKE '%' || ? || '%' OR subject COLLATE NOCASE LIKE '%' || ? || '%' OR intro COLLATE NOCASE LIKE '%' || ? || '%')


The exception does say there is a syntax error around IS, but I couldn't figure out where it's pointing to; I've gone through all of the related questions around this issue, and all I could find is using CASE (which I've already done in the above query) or checking if it's null or not, which I've already tested with the query mentioned above by modifying it like so:

"SELECT * FROM localMail " +
"WHERE (:senders IS NULL OR `from` IN (:senders))" +
"AND (isStarred = :inStarred OR isInTrash = :inTrash OR isInInbox = :inInbox OR hasAttachments = :hasAttachments OR isArchived = :inArchive) " +
"AND (TRIM(:query) <> '' AND TRIM(:query) IS NOT NULL) " +
"AND (rawMail COLLATE NOCASE LIKE '%' || :query || '%' OR subject COLLATE NOCASE LIKE '%' || :query || '%' OR intro COLLATE NOCASE LIKE '%' || :query || '%')"

Both of these changes result in the same runtime error. How can I resolve this issue?
Update
I've updated the query as follows:
@Query(
    "SELECT * FROM localMail WHERE " +
    "`from` IN (:senders)" +
    " AND (isStarred=:inStarred OR isInTrash = :inTrash OR isInInbox = :inInbox OR hasAttachments = :hasAttachments OR isArchived = :inArchive)" +
    " AND accountId = (SELECT accountId FROM localMailAccount WHERE isACurrentSession = 1 LIMIT 1)" +
    " AND (TRIM(:query) <> '' AND TRIM(:query) IS NOT NULL)" +
    "AND (rawMail COLLATE NOCASE LIKE '%' || :query || '%' OR subject COLLATE NOCASE LIKE '%' || :query || '%' OR intro COLLATE NOCASE LIKE '%' || :query || '%')"
)
fun queryCurrentSessionMails(
    senders: List<From>,
    query: String,
    hasAttachments: Boolean,
    inInbox: Boolean,
    inStarred: Boolean,
    inArchive: Boolean,
    inTrash: Boolean
): Flow<List<LocalMail>>


Although this doesn't throw any error, the data gets returned only if senders isn't empty. If it's empty, it returns nothing. However, I want to skip this condition and proceed with other conditions if senders is empty. If it's not empty, then apply it.

I've attached the respective images below:



if senders isn't empty, it applies the filter and returns the value:



If senders is empty, it returns nothing when it should return based on other conditions:



The issue is that you end up with CASE WHEN IS NOT NULL or WHERE IS NULL i.e. there is no expression/result for the WHEN/WHERE to examine/test.
If the list were not empty, and for example had 3 elements. then the SQL would  become CASE WHEN ?,?,? IS NOT NULL (again a syntax error) or WHERE ?,?,? IS NULL ... (yet again a syntax error).
Just use:-
WHERE `from` IN(:senders) ....

If the list (senders) is empty, then the resultant SQL is just IN() which always returns false.
If for example the list had 3 elements then the resultant SQL would be IN(?,?,?) the actual values being passed and bound when the SQL is executed, this would return true/false depending upon the underlying values.

In Room Lists are really only intended for use by IN.
If not used for IN there will always be problems with passing a List/collection as explained above.


Additional Considerations

Passing a null list as opposed to an empty list will result in a null pointer exception you should not use List<From>? but (see next point) List<From> and in the absence of items pass an empty List.
If From (the object of the List) is anything but a simple, single value, object then you may encounter difficulties each element in the list needs to equate to a single value i.e. a single ? to be substituted.

it is highly likely that the table is based upon the From class/object and as there are multiple columns in the from table that you will encounter issues.

the single value, assuming you are not using a composite primary key, would be to extract, from the List, and pass a List of the primary key values as these uniquely identify a row.



Additional Re comment and updated

If it's empty, it's supposed to skip to further conditions

Noting that List<From> has now been used, instead of List<From>? as advised then, I would suggest considering using:-
A change to the function in that you pass the size of the list e.g.:-
fun queryCurrentSessionMails(
        senders: List<From>,
        senders_count: Int, /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED Number of senders */
        query: String,
        hasAttachments: Boolean,
        inInbox: Boolean,
        inStarred: Boolean,
        inArchive: Boolean,
        inTrash: Boolean
    ): Flow<List<LocalMail>>

Now you can use :senders_count within the query something along the lines of:-
SELECT *
FROM localmail 
WHERE
    CASE  
        WHEN 1 /*<<<<<<<<<< # of elements in List as passed via :senders_count */ THEN `from` IN('Anne','Sue') 
        ELSE 1 /* other conditions */
    END
;


noting that where the 1 is you would have :senders
the above is used in an SQLite tool (Navicat) to demonstrate

Demonstration
Consider:-
/* Just in case Demo Environment is not clean, clean it up */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS localmail;
/* cut down verson of the table */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS localmail (`from` TEXT, rawMail TEXT /* .... */);
/* Add some data */
INSERT INTO localmail VALUES
    ('Fred','blah blah fred.'),
    ('Anne','blah blah anne.'),
    ('Sue','blah blah sue.'),
    ('Bert','blah blah bert.')
;

/* Demo where the senders (List<From> has some entries) therefore WHEN used */
SELECT *
FROM localmail 
WHERE
    CASE  
        WHEN 1 /*<<<<<<<<<< # of elements in List as passed via :senders_count */ THEN `from` IN('Anne','Sue') 
        ELSE 1 /* other conditions (1 used here would select ALL BUT ELSE is not used)*/
    END
;

/* Demo where the senders (List<From> has NO entries) therefore ELSE used*/
SELECT *
FROM localmail 
WHERE
    CASE  
        WHEN 0 /*<<<<<<<<<< # of elements in List as passed via :senders_count */ THEN `from` IN() 
        ELSE 1 /* other conditions (1 used here selects ALL) */
    END
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS localmail; /* Cleanup Demo Environment */

Results
The first select which indicates some element in the senders results in the expected "Anne" and "Sue". i.e. as List is not empty then the  listed rows are selected:-

The second select, where there are no elements in the senders (reflecting that senders_count is 0), results in the alternative ELSE being applied to the WHERE clause. Thus, as 1 (true) then ALL rows are selected:-

If the second select was instead:-
SELECT *
FROM localmail 
WHERE
    CASE  
        WHEN 0 /*<<<<<<<<<< # of elements in List as passed via :senders_count */ THEN `from` IN() 
        ELSE `from` LIKE '%r%' /* other conditions (1 used here selects ALL) */
    END
;


i.e. a more complex WHERE condition then the result would be:-



i.e. as expected fred and bert were selected according to the more complex WHERE clause.


This is only working when senders isn't empty. If it's empty, it's supposed to skip to further conditions since IN() always returns false. However, it returns the same empty list. I've updated the question including the screenshots; thanks :)
